# Session to connected app

Tags: rest-api, apexrest, connected-apps

I would like an API to behave dyanamically based on which Connected App is calling it.

Is there a way to identify from the user session which connected App was used to create the session?

I can then get the API to look up specific configuration for the associated Connected App.

I'm planning on storing configuration in a custom object with a name field matching the Connected App name.

Comment: waht do you mean by `behave differently`?

Comment: The API runs queries, and I want the predicate to be difference based on the calling user.   , or in my logical thinking, the application that is calling the API

Comment: Connected app is for authentication. Use profiles permission sets for authorisation.

Comment: Ok, that would work.  I could have a dedicated api user with a specifc profile, and link the custom config to that profile.  It would mean slightly more configuration.  The config isnt really authorisation related, but business logic behaviour based on the calling app.  But that would work. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/298792/re-purpose-connected-app-and-api-only-user/